# When button is clicked for the update mutation HttpLinkServerExtention is thrown

Tags: flutter, graphql, flutter-dependencies, prisma-graphql

Here is the response data:

`statusCode:400 body:"{"errors":[{"message":"String cannot represent a non string value: cl18ty12i0518m9p67q604waz","extensions":{"code":"GRAPHQL_VALI…" hashCode:438889705 runtimeType:Type (Response`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/urRB8.jpg

I tried to make change values to string to .toString() to no avail

Answer (score 0):

It worked by adding a single quote string in mutation ''